# php no puedo ordenar mis IFS

Tags: php, sql, condiciones

no puedo con algo tan basico y estoy trabado hace un par de horas, no puedo hacer funcionar mis dos if, por separado andan, las funciones y consultas estan bien realizadas pq fueron testeadas, pero no puedo hacerlas andar en una unica funcion, es un problema de if pero no puedo lograrlo hacer que funcionen... Les dejo mi codigo a ver si ustedes se dan cuenta... desde ya muchas gracias..

````
function getApiGames($params=null) {


if (!empty($_GET['sort']) && isset($_GET['sort'])) 

    if ($this->model->valueSort($_GET['sort']) == 0) {
            return $this->view->response("la columna " . $_GET['sort'] . " no existe, las que existen son: COMPLETAR JOAQUIN", 400);}



if (!empty($_GET['orderby']) && isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['limit']) && !empty($_GET['sort'])) {
        if (isset($_GET['orderby']) && isset($_GET['limit']) && isset($_GET['sort']) && !empty($_GET['filter']) && isset($_GET['filter'])) {
            if ($_GET['orderby'] == "DESC" || $_GET['orderby']  == "desc" || $_GET['orderby']  == "ASC" || $_GET['orderby']  == "asc") {
                if (!empty($_GET['page'] == 0)) {
                    return $this->view->response("la pagina no pede ser 0", 403);
                }
                $order = $_GET['orderby'];
                $page = $_GET['page'];
                $limit = $_GET['limit'];
                $sort = $_GET['sort'];
                $filter = $_GET['filter'];
                $games = $this->model->getAllGames($sort, $order, $page, $limit, $filter);
            } // FINALIZADA
    
            else {
                return $this->view->response("puede que el orderby este mal escrito, escribir DESC o desc, ASC o asc", 404);
            }
        }
    }
    
    else if (!empty($_GET['orderby']) && isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['limit']) && !empty($_GET['sort'])) {
        if (isset($_GET['orderby']) && isset($_GET['limit']) && isset($_GET['sort'])) {
            if ($_GET['orderby'] == "DESC" || $_GET['orderby']  == "desc" || $_GET['orderby']  == "ASC" || $_GET['orderby']  == "asc") {
                if (!empty($_GET['page'] == 0)) {
                    return $this->view->response("la pagina no pede ser 0", 403);
                }
                $order = $_GET['orderby'];
                $page = $_GET['page'];
                $limit = $_GET['limit'];
                $sort = $_GET['sort'];
    
                $games = $this->model->getAllGames($sort, $order, $page, $limit, null);
            } // FINALIZADA
    
            else {
                return $this->view->response("puede que el orderby este mal escrito, escribir DESC o desc, ASC o asc", 404);
            }
        }
    }
else {
        $games = $this->model->getAllGames();
    }
    return $this->view->response($games, 200);
    
    
    } ```


Gracias espero respuesta!
````

Comment: ¿Porqué usar conjuntamente `empty` con`isset`? Eso no tiene mucho sentido, según mi opinión.

Comment: Mi profesor de la facultad me lo pide, yo tampoco... Pero total de aprobar jaja... Tienes idea de mis errores de IF como pueden solucionarse? Es raro que me ande un if y el otro else if no, y viceversa cambiandolos...

Comment: En todo caso, si no quieres ver errores el dia que no haya el `GET['sort']`, cambia el orden de esto: `if (!empty($_GET['sort']) && isset($_GET['sort']))` por esto: `if (isset($_GET['sort']) && !empty($_GET['sort']))`, para impedir que primero intente calcular si el valor está vacio cuando aun no has comprobado si existe dicha variable. Y acostumbrate a usar siempre llaves en los **if**, pues allí no la estas usando y dificulta su lectura.